# Open atom without any files open

Tags: atom-editor

For Atom 1.14.3, I've opened a huge file in my project and it's causing out of memory issues and crashing my Atom.

I'm trying to reopen Atom for this project without it auto-opening the massive file which is causing the problems, yet it always auto opens that file despite my window restore option being set to `false` in my Config.cson:

```
core:
    restorePreviousWindowsOnStart: false
```

How can I open the project without any of the files open so I can continue working on it?

Comment: File a bug report on their issue tracker that `restorePreviousWindowsOnStart: false` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try opening Atom from terminal/command line with `--clear-window-state` option. It will still open the directory in tree view but won't load the files you have had opened.

Also bear in mind that this switch will destroy all unsaved changes. You may want to visit [Atom's Flight Manual's page](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#clearing-saved-state) for more information about this switch.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best answer, but it is an answer, so I'll give it a shot.

If you can open Atom at all, wait for your huge file to open once, then minimize that window, start Atom again. This will open a new window with one untitled page and nothing else. Minimize your new window, close your old one with the huge file. Now close your untitled page.

Because of how Atom's window restore works, it will re-open your last project, so now when it opens, it will open to the empty untitled page.

Hopefully that helps a little :/

Comment: Worked wonders. Much simpler than trying to open it from the terminal, and also pretty obvious when you think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

just type in the current directory (with the dot)

`atom .`

it will load the current directory tree, with no open files